# User control is hidden for Guest and Anonymous user in Enterprise portal in Dynamics AX

Tags: user-controls, hidden, anonymous, enterprise-portal

I have created web menu item for user control (.aspx page) and assigned it new privilege that is assigned to role of Guest and Anonymous vendor. However, it doesnt not show user control and hides it by default. Please let me know how to detail page and user control public for all users

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your Managed web content to appropriate privilege.